# How can I use the dynkin-diagrams library to draw a diagram with a pentagonal tail?

Tags: dynkin-diagrams

I'm working with Coxeter diagrams, and using the [`dynkin-diagrams` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/dynkin-diagrams). I have a Coxeter system with the following Coxeter matrix:

```
[ 1 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 ]
[ 3 1 3 2 2 2 2 2 ]
[ 2 3 1 3 2 2 2 2 ]
[ 2 2 3 1 3 2 2 3 ]
[ 2 2 2 3 1 3 2 2 ]
[ 2 2 2 2 3 1 3 2 ]
[ 2 2 2 2 2 3 1 3 ]
[ 2 2 2 3 2 2 3 1 ]
```

Here's a sketch of what the diagram would look like:

[image: Coxeter diagram with 8 nodes with 5 nodes arranged in a loop.]

The most complex similar group I had been able to draw to this point is:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{/Dynkin diagram/fold style/.style={}} % Make the fold look like an edge
The general case of rank 6 is the hypercompact group \begin{dynkinDiagram}[Coxeter]E{III}
  \dynkinRootMark{*}1
  \dynkinRootMark{*}6
\end{dynkinDiagram}
\end{document}
```

[image: Close group of size 6]

This works by tweaking the style of an existing group so it *looks like* a Coxeter diagram for my group.

However this has a bunch of issues:

- It messes with the fold styling meaning I can't have folds in the document if I use this technique.
- To my knowledge there is no way to label the folded edge.
- Since this uses a specific group which coincidentally looks like the group I'm interested in there's no way to extend it to other groups like the group at the lead of the question.

It seems like the package is intended for formatting diagrams for a very specific set of groups, namely those groups which have established names. I'm not dealing with these groups so I want to know if either I'm missing some tool in the package, or if it's just not the tool for this job.

Is the above diagram I want to draw possible with the `dynkin-diagrams` package or should I ditch the package and redraw my diagrams some other way?

Comment: Can you please add the code to your quesion? Do I get you right, you want all edges to be of equal length?

Comment: @MS-SPO I don't see why the code would be helpful, I might as well have drawn the diagram by hand. I don't mind if the edges are unequal length. What's really important here is whether this diagram can be drawn with the library. If lengths, angles and positions need to be altered for that to happen, that's ultimately fine, because.

Comment: Did you check its manual? https://mirror.clientvps.com/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/dynkin-diagrams/dynkin-diagrams.pdf

Comment: @MS-SPO Yes, I mentioned in the question that I read it. It's not very helpful to me. It seems like the documentation is mostly concerned with diagrams based around named groups, and unfortunately my applications involve very non-compact groups like the one in question.

Comment: Sorry, don't get what you are asking for. Suggestion: try to rework your question a little. // To avoid running into a discussion, which are not welcome here, I must say good bye now.

Comment: @MS-SPO I altered the title a bit, and removed a bunch of information from the body of the question. Does that make it clear?  If it's not clear please vote to close.

Comment: Did you consider contacting the author of the package?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the source for the library I was able to find a couple of undocumented and poorly documented features that allow this. Here are three ways I found to make the diagram:

### Quick and dirty

This first way is the shortest way to do it, but has a couple of drawbacks:

```latex
\begin{dynkinDiagram}[Coxeter,fold style/.style={}]E{III}
  \dynkinRootMark{*}1
  \dynkinRootMark{*}6
  \dynkin[at=(root 2)]A{**o}
\end{dynkinDiagram}
```

We draw EIII as done in the question as a base, then we draw another diagram of an A3 and position it so that it overlaps with the EIII.

[image: Quick and dirty]

This has some drawbacks:

- It's pretty specific to the particular diagram and is not very extensible.
- It involves overlapping nodes.
- I cannot draw folds on this diagram since I'm pretending folds are edges.

### Cleaner

It turns out that there are commands for drawing new nodes and edges from scratch. Why this incredibly useful feature is undocumented escapes me. But in this next example we start with EIII and draw in the extra nodes:

```latex
\makeatletter
\begin{dynkinDiagram}[Coxeter,fold style/.style={}]E{III}
  \dynkinRootMark{*}1
  \dynkinRootMark{*}6
  \dynkinRootMark{*}2
  \advance\dynkin@nodes by 2
  \dynkinPlaceRootRelativeTo{7}{2}{east}{below}{left}
  \dynkinRootMark{*}7
  \dynkinDefiniteSingleEdge{2}7
  \dynkinPlaceRootRelativeTo{8}{7}{east}{below}{left}
  \dynkinRootMark{o}8
  \dynkinDefiniteSingleEdge{7}8
\end{dynkinDiagram}
\makeatother
```

[image: Cleaner]

This still has the fold problem, which we will fix in the next one.

### From the ground up

Instead of starting with EIII as the base I can start with A4 and extend it using the same techniques.

```
\makeatletter
\begin{dynkinDiagram}[Coxeter]A{***o}
  \advance\dynkin@nodes by 4
  \dynkinPlaceRootRelativeTo{5}{1}{northwest}{above}{left}
  \dynkinRootMark{*}5
  \dynkinDefiniteSingleEdge 1 5
  \dynkinPlaceRootRelativeTo{6}{1}{southwest}{below}{left}
  \dynkinRootMark{*}6
  \dynkinDefiniteSingleEdge 1 6
  \dynkinPlaceRootRelativeTo{7}{5}{west}{above}{left}
  \dynkinRootMark{*}7
  \dynkinDefiniteSingleEdge 5 7
  \dynkinPlaceRootRelativeTo{8}{6}{west}{below}{left}
  \dynkinRootMark{*}8
  \dynkinDefiniteSingleEdge 6 8
  \dynkinDefiniteSingleEdge 7 8
\end{dynkinDiagram}
\makeatother
```

[image: From the ground up]